# Prevent page scroll on ui-grid field click

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

How to stop a page from `scroll`, when `clicked` on any of the row field in `ui-grid`

I have a page with `ui-grid`, and in that each row contains an anchor tag with some `url` value linked and `target="_blank"` to open in new tab like below

```
<a ng-href="www.google.com" target="_blank">Click here</a>
```

When I click on any of the link, new tab opens and then if I come back to previous tab, page is getting scrolled up

This causing only for the first time. If I click on any of the link in the grid for second time, everything working fine

Somebody please suggest me solution...thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grid height that causing the page to scroll is causing the issue. So, reducing the grid height solved the issue.